# Gatsby JS multiples content type

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I got this graphql in my project :

```js
export const query = graphql`
query($id: String!) {
    post: markdownRemark(id: { eq : $id }, fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/posts/"}) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY", , locale: "fr-FR")
        slug
        title
      }
      id
      excerpt(format: PLAIN, pruneLength: 150, truncate: false)
    }
  }
`
```

When i got to /blog/[my article name], i see the post and it work perfectly.

If i do /blog/fzejifzjfzfiz i got a 404 error cause the post don't exist, perfect too.

But if i do /blog/null, i got an error page "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'frontmatter')"

complete code :
https://github.com/florent6001/florent-vandroy.fr

Actually, i don't have gatsby-node.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem, the problem wasn't coming from graphQL but by the gatbyJS page generator.

So i created my own gatsby-node.js for create the page like i want.
I removed both {MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js and created a template folder with blogPost and page template.

Here is my gatsby-node.js now :

```js
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {

    const post = await graphql(`
        query BlogPosts {
            allMarkdownRemark(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/posts/"}}) {
                nodes {
                    frontmatter {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    post.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
        actions.createPage({
            path: '/blog/' + node.frontmatter.slug,
            component: path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js'),
            context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug }
        })
    })

    const pages = await graphql(`
        query pages {
            allMarkdownRemark(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/pages/"}}) {
                nodes {
                    frontmatter {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    pages.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
        actions.createPage({
            path: node.frontmatter.slug,
            component: path.resolve('./src/templates/page.js'),
            context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug }
        })
    })
}
```